# bake IK bone position

Tags: actions

All I want to do is pose an IK chain with its controller bone. Then I want to store the position of the bones in the chain as a key frame, so they stay there when I turn off the IK constraint. I played with the bake action function, but to no avail. There must be a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to bake the action checking "Visual Keying" and "Overwrite current action" and have bake data set to "Pose" in order to work.

Then you can decide wheter or not bake only selected bones, clean curves leaving off unnecessary keyframes, clear constraints or leave them on.

If this doesn't solve, please upload your armature.

Comment: I hadn't considered "Visual Keying". That did the trick. Thanks.